# After supervisord crash, how to restart without killing all process?

Tags: supervisord

I have an issue where supervisord is crashing due to out of memory conditions. I know what is causing this (other processes consuming too much memory), but it's going to take a little time to fix.  In the meantime, I would like to bring supervisor back up if it crashes.  The problem here seems to be that it will not pick up where it left off and forgets about all the existing processes.  It seems to just attempt to restart all processes instead of recognizing that they were already running.

Is this a problem in my config (pid files not in the right place or something, it seems correct though) or is this just how supervisord works? Are there any workarounds to get the manager process to continue where it left off before it crashed?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is how supervisor works.

Comment: I was thinking we could add a reattach functionality to it where the pid files are inspected, and if we see the process still running that matches then we reattach it to supervisord.  Thanks for confirming that I wasn't just missing it.

Comment: I am not sure it is possible. From the website: "Supervisord starts processes as subprocesses, so it always knows the true up/down status of its children and can be queried conveniently for this data." I am quite sure supervisord does not use pid files.

Comment: I forgot about that. It's not just tracking, but an actual subprocess.  I'm not aware of any way to adopt processes that lost their parent process.  Thanks!